# Slow widget container control delays the rendering of the main page

Tags: xpages, xpages-extlib

Hello,
I'm using the widget container Control from the extension library.

I include several widgets in a main Xpage. They contains either a view panel control, either a repeat control based on a DbLookup function, either a document or any other content ....

One of them takes long time for rendering its content, then the Xpage is not rendered until the slowest widget is ready.
How to get the Xpage rendered with the other parts of the xpage even if one widget is still being rendered (like in the widgets page in Connections ) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try to wrap the widget content inside a djContentPane

```
<xe:djContentPane id="djContentPane1" partialRefresh="true" loadingMessage="loading..." errorMessage="Error" refreshOnShow="true" preload="true">Widget Content</xe:djContentPane>
```